# Flask html templates inheritance issue - mixed elements

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

everyone! I have an issue when inheriting from another template in Flask. My first file layout.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Flask</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Some header</h1>
    </header>
    <content>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </content>
</body>
</html>
```

Second one "main.html":

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}<p>test</p>{% endblock %}
```

Everything looks ok but when I load the page in browser the elements looks like this(everything from head is moved to body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Flask</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<header>
        <h1>Some header</h1>
</header>
<content>
    <p>test</p>
</content>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: cannot reproduce, did you try different browsers ?

Comment: Both Chrome and IE shows the same

Comment: something in the JS script could be guilty ?

Comment: Tried without JS - the same issue. When I render layout.html instead of main.html everything works fine

Comment: what version of flask are you using ? 0.12.2 seems to work great

Comment: just updated to 0.12.2 from 0.12 - nothing has changed

Comment: interestingly, in browser's dev view in source page everything is ok. only in elements things are mixed

Comment: have you tried using `{% block head %}` inside the `<head>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a little bit too late... The issue was, that I'd changed my IDE. Before I'd used PyCharm, then I switched to Visual Studio. It looks like they both use different encoding and something broke during migration. Creating new file and copying content was the solution.